# i can't find the resonant frequency in a rlc circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, frequency

I have an exercise where I have to find the resonant frequency but the equation can't be solve.

What happen in those cases? It is possible to say that te RCL circuit does not have a resonant frequency?

[image]

Comment: What equation can't be solved? Show us the equation.

Comment: @Marla i already edited the post

Comment: What were the actual values for R, C and L?

Comment: Can you share the circuit schematic?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. It's something called a biquadratic equation. We can do a sustitution z = w^2 to transform it to a standard quadratic equation.